# What testing tools and methods did Corey Haines use at GoGaRuCo 2011?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing

In [this video from GoGaRuCo 2011](http://lanyrd.com/2011/gogaruco/shmhw/), Corey Haines shows some techniques for making Rails test suites much faster. I would summarize it as follows:

- Put as much of your code as possible outside the Rails app, into other modules and classes
- Test those separately, without the overhead of loading up Rails
- Use them from within your Rails app

There were a couple of things I didn't understand, though.

- He alternates between running tests with `rspec` and `spn` or `spna` (for example, at about 3:50). Is `spn` a commonly-known tool?
- In his tests for non-Rails classes and modules, he includes the module or class being tested, but I don't see him including anything like `spec_helper`. How does he have Rspec available?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Sorry about the confusion. `spn` and `spna` are aliases I have that add my non-rails code to rspec's load path. There isn't anything special about them, other than adding a `-I path_to_code` on the command-line.

These days, I add something like this to my `.rspec` file:

```
-I app/mercury_app
```

Then I can do simple `require 'object_name'` at the top of my specs.

As for not including `spec_helper`: that is true, I don't. When you execute your spec file with `rspec <path_to_spec_file>`, it gets interpreted, so you don't need to require `rspec` explicitly.

For my db specs these days, I also have built an `active_record_spec_helper` which requires active_record, establishes a connection to the test database, and sets up `database_cleaner`; this allows me to simply require my model at the top of my spec file. This way, I can test the AR code against the db without having to load up my whole app.

A client I am working at where we are using these techniques is interested in supporting some blog posts about this, so hopefully they will start coming out towards the middle of June.

Comment: Will do. I'm also working on a video series which, while not specifically focused on this, will be about the decisions and techniques of building a rails application.

Comment: I accepted your answer because I consider you the world's foremost authority on Corey Haines.

Comment: HAHA! Thanks. I'm glad that my answer on corey haines' technique was accepted. :)
I'm looking forward to starting some of these posts.

Comment: Hi @coreyhaines. Have you gotten to writing the blog posts you mentioned above? If so, could you share the link to them here?